# Code coverage in system tests

Tags: ncover

We've got automated coverage builds, but they only give us numbers for our unit tests. We've also got a bunch of system tests.

This leaves us with two problems: some code looks uncovered even though it's used in the system tests (WCF endpoints, DB access, etc.); and some code looks covered even though it's only used by the unit tests.

How do I set up NCover (running on a build server) to get coverage numbers from *that process* (a service) while running *these unit tests*? All of the processes are on the same box.

In fact, we have two services talking to each other, and both communicate with an ASP.NET MVC app and an IIS-hosted WCF service; so it's actually multiple processes.

(.NET 4.0, x64. Using NUnit and MSpec. CI server is TeamCity.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, are *over there* and *over here* on the same build server?

If so, I assume the basic issue is how to cover multiple services (sorry If I've oversimplified).

If that's true, unfortunately, NCover 3 can't profile more than one service at a time. However, you can cover each service individually (sequentially, not simultaneously) and then merge the coverage files.

I realize this means running NCover a couple of times in your build script, but from a coverage perspective, that's how it would work.

Does this help?

Comment: Yes. Same box; I've edited the question. Do you mean that we could run NCover multiple times at the same time, to cover each service?

Comment: I edited the answer -- only one instance of the profiler can be run at a time.